# Solve the following recurrence relation: $a_{n}=10a_{n-2}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I'm trying to solve the following recurrence equation $a_{n}=10a_{n-2}$.

Initial conditions: $a_0=1$, $a_1=10$

I have tried to use characteristic polynomial and generating functions but both methods lead to contradiction.

I think I should observe $\mathbb{N}_{even}$ and $\mathbb{N}_{odd}$ as different cases but I don't know how to do it formally.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain how the characteristic polynomial leads to a contradiction?

Comment: The solutions are $10^{0.5}$ and $-10^{0.5}$ and then I get a contradiction while calculating the coefficients.

Comment: Well, since you don't give any initial conditions...how do you even try to compute the coefficients?

Comment: You need two initial values, $a_0$ and $a_1$ say.

Comment: @lulu You are right, fixed that.

Comment: I mean, you could just write $a_{2n}=10^na_0$, and $a_{2n+1}=10^na_1$ if you want...but there is nothing wrong with the characteristic polynomial method.

Comment: @GADI The odd and even series are independent of each other.

Comment: I see the edit, so writing $a_n=A\left( \sqrt {10} \right)^n+B \left( -\sqrt {10} \right)^n$ we get $1=a_0=A+B, 10=a_1=(A-B)(\sqrt {10})$.

Comment: @lulu Yes. That's a contradiction, doesn't it? you get $0=10^{0.5}$

Comment: Where is there a contradiction?

Comment: You get $0=\sqrt {10}$

Comment: Really?  I get $A=\frac {\sqrt {10}+10}{2\sqrt {10}}, B=\frac {\sqrt {10}-10}{2\sqrt {10}}$.  I don't see any problem at all.

Comment: I mean, the linear forms $A+B$ and $(A-B)(\sqrt {10})$ are linearly independent, so how could there possibly be a contradiction?

Comment: Yes. I made an algebraic mistake. Thank you for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need initial values for $ a_0 $ and for $a_1$ to start with.

Notice that, $$ a_2 = 10a_0$$,$$a_4 = 10a_2 =10^2a_0$$  $$ a_6=10a_4 =10^3 a_0$$

With the given initial values we get  $$a_{2k}=10^ka_0 = 10^k $$

Similarly you get $$a_{2k+1}=10^{k+1}  $$

Comment: With the specific initial conditions, this can be condensed in a single formula: $$a_n=10^{\bigl\lceil \tfrac n2\bigr\rceil}.$$

Comment: @Bernard very true and smart.